# How do I serve Excel spreadsheets to IOS9 over the web?

Tags: excel, safari, ios9

I have an authenticated website that hosts Excel spreadsheets. Apple users have been able to view those spreadsheets satisfactorily in Safari. But in IOS9, the .xlsx spreadsheets no longer display correctly, showing only the headers and none of the content. The relevant HTTP headers are

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="sheet.xlsx"
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

I can't help but notice that I have Excel installed on the iPad, and yet I'm viewing the document in buggy Safari. Is there a way to get my document from Safari to Excel, or a header I can set to allow this?

(Using iOS 9.1 and Excel, Safari *finally* displays an "Open in Excel" option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also see this behaviour.

Opening xlsx files over SSL in Safari on iOS 9 only displays headers.

It works properly in Chrome and Dolphin on iOS 9 and Safari works fine on iOS 8 devices.

**Edit:** Using web inspector I was able to see that javascript and css files were being blocked. 
Here are the warnings.

```
[Warning] [blocked] The page at [URL] was not allowed to run insecure content 
from x-apple-ql-id://C18FD844-A305-415A-8096-90DFD8D43CA8/x-apple-ql-magic/Tabs.js.

[Warning] [blocked] The page at [URL] was not allowed to run insecure content 
from x-apple-ql-id://018921C7-D074-4763-8838-E44E535A65F4/x-apple-ql-magic/Tabs.css.
```

And an Error

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ReloadFirstSheetIfNeeded
```

Comment: So what's the answer?

Comment: I logged a bug report with apple. Looks to me like they don't trust themselves. My guess is whatever serves "x-apple-ql-id" doesn't support TLS1.2 which iOS 9 now requires.

Comment: By all accounts the answer is No.

Comment: iOS 9.0.2 Does **NOT** fix this issue

Comment: iOS 9.1 Also does not fix this issue :(

Comment: iOS 9.3 fixes his issue!! About time